# How To Use An onclick Function To Check Class Name Without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am looking to check if a element has a class name on click. I have the click event calling the function but nothing logs to the console. Interestingly, document.write works but no matter what I click, it logs the else even if the HTML element has the class name.

**HTML**

```
<p>What is 2+2?</p>
<a href="#" class="answer wrong">5</a>
<a href="#" class="answer correct">4</a>
<a href="#" class="answer wrong">7</div>
<a href="#" class="answer wrong">2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
var wrongMsg = "Sorry, that's not the answer"
var correctMsg = "Correct!"
var answers = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");

for (var i=answers.length; i--;){
    answers[i].addEventListener('click', checkMulti);
};

function checkMulti(){
    if ( this.className == "correct" ){
        console.log(correctMsg);
    }else{
        console.log(wrongMsg);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) gets the `class` attribute value. So it would be `"answer correct"` rather than just `"correct"`. Instead you will want to see if it's in the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) or split by space the `className` property (*since this is better supported*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the method `contains` from `classList`.

```js
var wrongMsg = "Sorry, that's not the answer"
var correctMsg = "Correct!"
var answers = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");

for (var i = answers.length; i--;) {
  answers[i].addEventListener('click', checkMulti);
};

function checkMulti() {
  if (this.classList.contains("correct")) {
    console.log(correctMsg);
  } else {
    console.log(wrongMsg);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>What is 2+2?</p>
<a href="#" class="answer wrong">5</a>
<a href="#" class="answer correct">4</a>
<a href="#" class="answer wrong">7</div>
<a href="#" class="answer wrong">2</div>
```

## Resource

- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 0):

I believe correct approach would you to look for `correct` classname in element's `classList` property

like so: `this.classList.contains("correct");`

more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList